# Folder Does Not Support Ordering

Tags: plone

I see a message **This type of folder does not support ordering** when viewing the News or Events folder. My understanding is that items contained in such folder, their position order can not be set arbitrarily. Only alphabetical order for their IDs is applied.

[image: Info message is enabled by wildcard.foldercontents]

From ZMI, I see News and Events folders are of ATFolder type, everything seems the same with the regular folder I just create. What makes such difference? And what is the rationale behind this?

Edit: My bad that **Info** message in the above image is enabled by wildcard.foldercontents, which I thought due to Plone 4.3.2. However, the issue remains that position order can not be set arbitrarily. The following image attached to illustrate this.

[image: Arbitrarily set position order will be reset alphabetically]

PS: I ever delete the News folder, create a regular folder named *news*, this way I can set item position order arbitrarily. However, I find the Calendar Portlet within that folder is not working right. The issue happens when I click to switch months. The URL link will be out of its context, I mean, not staying in the news folder. Maybe this is not related to the folder ordering behavior, anyway, just for your reference.

[image]

Comment: The calendar portlet links is a caching issue. In addition, the next pages should really be rendered with ajax.

Comment: Fixed the calendar link issue: https://github.com/plone/plone.app.portlets/commit/ca54cd3a74d62d10185a03c46aa334d994167141

Comment: and: https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFPlone/commit/d09a486d386e34af74b62650494e413b10526357

Comment: @vangheem Thanks! This reminds me that happens randomly, which seems evidence of caching issue. Glad to see Plone get improved like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason Plone is shipping with the news and events folders being unorderable.

```
>>> news = site.news
>>> news.getOrdering()
<plone.folder.unordered.UnorderedOrdering object at 0x112e434d0>
```

I consider this a bug in plone's initial site installation.

Plone core actually explicitly sets the folder to unordered: https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFPlone/blob/4.3.x/Products/CMFPlone/setuphandlers.py#L250

I don't understand why. I'll change it if there aren't any objections...

Comment: This is probably a side effect of the transition from (unordered) Large Plone Folders, which were necessary in Plone 3 when dealing with many items, for performance reasons. There's still a small benefit for folders with thousands of items, because there's no stored list of contained ids that needs to be updated whenever items are added/removed. But it's probably okay to change these back to ordered folders and let integrators building large sites change that if necessary.

Comment: +1 for changing all folders to be ordered by default and David's arguments.

Comment: done https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFPlone/commit/1471828ee97a8dd84396bad4a3286be514819869